# Как в pom.xml загрузить зависимость aar с другой зависимостью aar?

Tags: java, maven

Загружаю такую зависимость

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>androidx.navigation</groupId>
        <artifactId>navigation-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```

У нее в зависимостях matrerial 1.0.0
Добавляю в зависимости

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.material</groupId>
        <artifactId>material</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Пишет ошибку:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   org.hello:gs-maven-android:apk:0.1.0: Failure to find
>   com.google.android.material:material:jar:1.0.0 in
>   https://maven.google.com/ was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   mvnrepository has elapsed or updates are forced

То есть оно пытается найти jar, хотя jar нет на репозитории, только aar. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

На сайте зависимости [`androidx.navigation`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.navigation/navigation-ui/2.1.0) указано что используется `Google` репозиторий:

> Note: this artifact it located at Google repository
>   (https://maven.google.com/)

Вам нужно добавить в Ваш `pom.xml` запись об этом репозитории:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>google</id>
      <url>https://maven.google.com</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

К слову. Зависимость `com.google.android.material` загрузится автоматически при подключении `androidx.navigation` зависимости. Отдельно её прописывать в `pom.xml` не надо.

[Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

Comment: Репозиторий прописан. При этом найти все равно не может. 
Вот скрин ошибки https://i.imgur.com/D8q161M.png
Тут material не прописан и maven сам лезет искать его, но не находит. По ошибке вижу, что он ищет jar, а не aar. Когда прописываю зависимости aar вручную добавляю <type>aar</type>, а тут так понимаю надо сделать чтобы оно само искало aar. Может это где-то прописать нужно?

Comment: Скрин `pom.xml` Вашего с репозиторием.

Comment: Вот минимальный pom.xml, при котором возникает ошибка
https://i.imgur.com/5GGrYrl.png